# Starting AsyncTasks from Handlers in Android

Tags: android, handlers

How does the handler message queue work? I know for a fact that the message queue is tied to the thread it is initialized in. If i have 2 tasks(each download from the web), and I initiate an async task from the handler,one for each, will the 2 tasks be executed simultaneously?

I just need to understand, how the queue works.. 
could anyone please help! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, `AsyncTask` can be executed only on the UI thread. So, even if you have two separate handlers (one for each `AsyncTask`) they should be both associated with the UI thread.

Secondary, several `AsyncTask` instances may run either simultaneously or one by one. It depends on the API version. It is better to read [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) about this:

> public final AsyncTask execute (Params... params)
>
> Executes the task with the specified parameters.
>   The task returns itself (this) so that the caller can keep a reference
>   to it.
>
> Note: this function schedules the task on a queue for a single
>   background thread or pool of threads depending on the platform
>   version. When first introduced, AsyncTasks were executed serially on a
>   single background thread. Starting with DONUT, this was changed to a
>   pool of threads allowing multiple tasks to operate in parallel.
>   Starting HONEYCOMB, tasks are back to being executed on a single
>   thread to avoid common application errors caused by parallel
>   execution. If you truly want parallel execution, you can use the
>   executeOnExecutor(Executor, Params...) version of this method with
>   THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR; however, see commentary there for warnings on
>   its use.

Comment: Thanks a ton.. appreciate it :)

Comment: Accept the answer if you satisfied with it.